# Run QEMU command with cron

Tags: cron, qemu

I have a machine that, aside of other services, needs to run a server VM. I'm running the VM with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 8G \
    -smp 2 \
    -hda gw_disk.qcow2
```

This is on a script `start.sh` and then I have on the root crontab (`sudo crontab -e`):

`@reboot cd /disk/folder && setsid ./start.sh`

After reboot I look at `/var/log/syslog` and I get this:

```
(CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
(root) CMD (cd /disk/folder && setsid ./start.sh)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I can't find the process with `ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | grep qemu`

Any idea what I'am missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things jump out at me here

1. Consider installing `libvirt` with its `virsh`, or something similar, so that you have a management layer around your VM
2. Capture the output of your crontab entry. It's telling you there's output but that it can't email it to you ("*info (No MTA installed, discarding output)*"). You can either write it to the system logger or directly to a file:

   ```
   # Direct to a logfile (remember to rotate/truncate it periodically)
   @reboot ( echo "Starting: $(date)"; cd /disk/folder && setsid ./start.sh ) >>/var/log/startvm.log 2>&1

   # To the logger subsystem (usually ends up in /var/log/user.log)
   @reboot ( cd /disk/folder && setsid ./start.sh ) 2>&1 | logger -t startvm
   ```
3. Consider using a systemd unit to start the process rather than a boot-time crontab entry. Initially more complicated, certainly, but easier to maintain once you have it and with better logging and failure reporting

   References:

   - [Use systemd to Start a Linux Service at Boot](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/start-service-at-boot/) on Akamai/Linode
   - [How do I run a single command at startup using systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/919054/473234) on Ask Ubuntu